Optimizing SQLAlchemy multi-table insert to MySQL with relationships
I have a function that inserts large amounts of data (models, dashboards, formulas, graphs) into a database while maintaining relationships (e.g., parent-child, foreign keys). The current implementation works but is slow due to multiple db.flush() calls after each batch insert. I want to optimize it to reduce flushes and improve performance while preserving relationships.
Mysql, on aurora DB.
Name: SQLAlchemy
Version: 2.0.36
Problem:
The optimized code fails to correctly populate old-to-new ID mappings after flushes. Relationships (e.g., parent IDs, foreign keys) remain unset or invalid, causing validation errors and broken references.
Goal:
How can I optimize these inserts while ensuring relationships are preserved and ID mappings are correctly populated?
What I Tried:
Reduced the number of flushes by grouping inserts into phases (e.g., models → dashboards → formulas).
Used db.bulk_insert_mappings for faster inserts where possible.
Attempted to update parent IDs and references after minimal flushes.
What I Expected:
Faster execution by minimizing flushes and database round-trips.
Correct old-to-new ID mappings after flushes to update relationships properly.
code:
@time_function(log_to_db_enabled=True)
def apply_template(self, db: Session, data: TemplateJsonSchema, company_id: int, payload: ApplyTemplateSchema):
    """

        @param payload: ApplyTemplateSchema
        @param db:
        @param data: ApplyTemplateSchema: Contains information about the models, dashboards, formulas, company ID, template ID, and start date.
        @param company_id:
        @return:int: Returns the unique identifier of the applied template.
        """
    """
        Description:
            Applies a template to the database, creating associated model calculations, dashboards, and formulas.
        Details:
            - This method applies a template to the database, creating necessary entries for model calculations, dashboards, and formulas.
            - The 'data' parameter contains comprehensive information about models, dashboards, formulas, company ID, template ID, and start date.
            - A new entry for the template is created in the database with the provided company ID, template ID, and start date.
            - Associated model calculations are added to the database, linked to the template.
            - Dashboards and their related graphs are added, ensuring correct associations with model calculations.
            - Formulas are added, with proper references to corresponding model calculations.
            - The unique identifier of the applied template is returned.
        """
    try:
        graph_domain = GraphDomain(
            GraphRepository(),
            GraphOptionsRepository(),
            GraphLayoutDataRepository(),
            GraphDataPointRepository(),
            DataGroupRepository(),
        )

        template_id = payload.template_id
        branch_id = payload.target_branch_id

        active_template = ActiveTemplate(company_id=company_id, template_id=template_id,
                                         start_date=payload.start_date, branch_id=branch_id)
        db.add(active_template)
        db.flush()

        old_id_to_model = {}
        for model_attributes in data.models:
            old_id = model_attributes.id
            model_attributes.active_template_id = active_template.id
            model_attributes.company_id = company_id
            model_attributes.branch_id = branch_id
            model = ModelCalculation(**model_attributes.model_dump())
            model.id = None
            old_id_to_model[old_id] = model

        db.add_all(old_id_to_model.values())
        db.flush()

        # update model_id in dashboard to new ids
        old_id_to_dashboard = {}
        for dashboard_attributes in data.dashboards:
            old_id = dashboard_attributes.id
            dashboard_attributes.model_id = old_id_to_model.get(dashboard_attributes.model_id).id
            dashboard_attributes.branch_id = branch_id
            dashboard_attributes.company_id = company_id
            dashboard = Dashboard(**dashboard_attributes.model_dump())
            dashboard.id = None
            old_id_to_dashboard[old_id] = dashboard

        db.add_all(old_id_to_dashboard.values())
        db.flush()

        old_id_to_formula = {}
        old_id_to_parent_id = {}  # Store the original parent_id

        for formula_attributes in data.formulas:
            old_id = formula_attributes.id
            # safe extract model_id with get
            new_model_id = old_id_to_model.get(formula_attributes.model_id)
            if not new_model_id:
                logging.error(f"Model with id {formula_attributes.model_id} not found on formula {old_id}", exc_info=True)
                continue
            formula_attributes.model_id = old_id_to_model.get(formula_attributes.model_id).id
            formula_attributes.branch_id = branch_id

            # Store original parent_id before setting it to None
            old_id_to_parent_id[old_id] = formula_attributes.parent_id
            formula_attributes.parent_id = None  # Temporarily set parent_id to None

            formula = Formula(**formula_attributes.model_dump())
            formula.id = None
            old_id_to_formula[old_id] = formula

        db.add_all(old_id_to_formula.values())
        db.flush()

        formula_id_original_to_clone = {old_id: formula.id for old_id, formula in old_id_to_formula.items()}

        # Now update the parent_ids using the original stored parent_id
        for old_id, formula in old_id_to_formula.items():
            original_parent_id = old_id_to_parent_id[old_id]

            if original_parent_id:  # Only set if there was a parent_id originally
                formula.parent_id = formula_id_original_to_clone.get(original_parent_id)

        # id_mapping type Dict[Type[Base], Dict[int, int]]
        id_mapping = {Formula: formula_id_original_to_clone}

        update_cloned_formulas_expression(cloned_objects=list(old_id_to_formula.values()), id_mapping=id_mapping,
                                          allow_original_parent_id=True, update_parent_id=True)
        # flush updated cloned formulas
        db.flush()

        for graph_attributes in data.graphs:
            # update old dashboard id to clone dashboard id
            old_dashboard_id = graph_attributes.graph_data.dashboard_id
            graph_attributes.graph_data.dashboard_id = old_id_to_dashboard.get(old_dashboard_id).id
            graph_attributes.graph_data.branch_id = branch_id

            for data_group in graph_attributes.data_groups:
                for data_point in data_group.data_points:
                    data_point.formula_id = formula_id_original_to_clone.get(data_point.formula_id, data_point.formula_id)
            graph_domain.create(db=db, data=GraphCreateSchema(**graph_attributes.model_dump()))

        db.commit()
        return active_template

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error applying template: {e}", exc_info=True)
        db.rollback()
        raise e


What database are you using and what version of sqlalchemy?

Mysql, on aurora DB.
Name: SQLAlchemy
Version: 2.0.36

Bummer I don't think mysql supports INSERT ... RETURNING ... statement.  Are the template models in the same database that you are trying to populate with them?   ie.data.dashboards is in the same db as the Dashboard(**dashboard_attributes.model_dump())?

If it is the same db then I think you can just copy the data from the source template into the destination table and update the fks at the same time except for the initial active template.

Its stored as json schema on active template

How many records are you actually inserting?  Also how "slow" is it ?

This would be a lot easier if you stored the template in parallel with the destination tables but this is an example using an insert then patch strategy.

insert the active template and use its id to isolate all the remaining data
insert in the cloned data, passing in the old ids and old foreign keys
update the cloned records by following the old relationships with a JOIN and fixing the foreign keys
select back the ORM objects using loaders to reduce the query count

import os
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Column,
    Integer,
    DateTime,
    ForeignKey
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship, Session, selectinload, aliased
from sqlalchemy.sql import insert, update, select
from datetime import datetime
from random import randint



Base = declarative_base()


class ActiveTemplate(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'active_templates'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # The template we cloned.
    template_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    company_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    branch_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    start_date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    models = relationship("ModelCalculation",  back_populates="active_template")
    dashboards = relationship("Dashboard",  back_populates="active_template")
    formulas = relationship("Formula",  back_populates="active_template")

class ModelCalculation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'models'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # Our old id in the template we were cloned from.
    old_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    # From clone.
    payload = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    # THIS clone.
    active_template_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("active_templates.id"))
    active_template = relationship("ActiveTemplate",  back_populates="models")
    dashboards = relationship("Dashboard",  back_populates="model")
    formulas = relationship("Formula", back_populates="model")


class Dashboard(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dashboards'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # Our old id in the template we were cloned from.
    old_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, index=True)
    # Allow null so we can "fix up" the fks.
    model_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("models.id"), nullable=True)
    # The model id in the source template.
    old_model_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, index=True)
    # From clone.
    payload = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    # THIS clone.
    active_template_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("active_templates.id"))
    active_template = relationship("ActiveTemplate",  back_populates="dashboards")
    model = relationship("ModelCalculation",  back_populates="dashboards")


class Formula(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'formulas'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # Our old id in the template we were cloned from.
    old_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, index=True)
    # Allow null so we can "fix up" the fks.
    model_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("models.id"), nullable=True)
    # The model id in the source template.
    old_model_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, index=True)
    # From clone.
    payload = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("formulas.id"), nullable=True)
    old_parent_id = Column(Integer, nullable=True, index=True)

    # THIS clone.
    active_template_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("active_templates.id"))

    children = relationship("Formula",  back_populates="parent")
    parent = relationship("Formula",  back_populates="children", remote_side=[id])
    active_template = relationship("ActiveTemplate",  back_populates="formulas")
    model = relationship("ModelCalculation",  back_populates="formulas")


def get_engine(env):
    return create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg://{env['DB_USER']}:{env['DB_PASSWORD']}@{env['DB_HOST']}:{env['DB_PORT']}/{env['DB_NAME']}", echo=True)


def init_db(conn):
    Base.metadata.create_all(conn, checkfirst=True)
    conn.commit()


@dataclass
class ApplyTemplateSchema:
    template_id: int
    target_branch_id: int
    start_date: datetime


@dataclass
class ModelSchema:
    id: int
    payload: int = field(default_factory=lambda: randint(0, 1000))


@dataclass
class DashboardSchema:
    id: int
    model_id: int
    payload: int = field(default_factory=lambda: randint(0, 1000))


@dataclass
class FormulaSchema:
    id: int
    payload: int
    model_id: int
    parent_id: None|int = None


@dataclass
class TemplateJsonSchema:
    models: list[ModelSchema]
    dashboards: list[DashboardSchema]
    formulas: list[FormulaSchema]



def mock_apply_template(db):
    models = []
    dashboards = []
    formulas = []

    # Used to generate fake dashboard ids.
    dashboard_id = 1
    formula_id = 1

    MODEL_COUNT = 1000
    DASHBOARD_COUNT = 20
    FORMULA_COUNT = 50
    SUBFORMULA_COUNT = 15
    for model_id in range(1, MODEL_COUNT):
        model = ModelSchema(id=model_id, payload=randint(0, 1000))
        for _ in range(randint(0, DASHBOARD_COUNT)):
            dashboard = DashboardSchema(id=dashboard_id, model_id=model_id, payload=randint(0, 1000))
            dashboard_id += 1
            dashboards.append(dashboard)
        for _ in range(randint(0, FORMULA_COUNT)):
            formula = FormulaSchema(id=formula_id, payload=randint(0, 50), model_id=model.id)
            formula_id += 1
            formulas.append(formula)
            for _ in range(randint(0, SUBFORMULA_COUNT)):
                sub = FormulaSchema(id=formula_id, payload=randint(0, 50), parent_id=formula.id, model_id=model.id)
                formula_id += 1
                formulas.append(sub)
        models.append(model)
    fake_data = TemplateJsonSchema(
        models=models,
        formulas=formulas,
        dashboards=dashboards)
    fake_payload = ApplyTemplateSchema(
        # Made up
        template_id = 10,
        target_branch_id = 5,
        start_date=datetime(day=25, month=12, year=2024)
        )
    fake_company_id = 100
    active_template = apply_template(db, fake_data, fake_company_id, fake_payload)

    print (len(active_template.models))
    print (sum(len(model.dashboards) for model in active_template.models))
    print (f"{active_template.id=}, {active_template.template_id=}")
    total_count = 0
    for model in active_template.models:
        total_count += 1
        print (f"\t{model.id=}, {model.old_id=}, {model.active_template_id=}")
        for dashboard in model.dashboards:
            total_count += 1
            print (f"\t\t{dashboard.id=}, {dashboard.old_id=}, {dashboard.model_id=}, {dashboard.old_model_id=}, {dashboard.active_template_id=}")
        for formula in model.formulas:
            total_count += 1
            # Root formulas only.
            if formula.parent_id is None:
                total_count += 1
                print (f"\t\t{formula.id=}, {formula.old_id=}, {formula.model_id=}, {formula.old_model_id=}, {formula.parent_id=}, {formula.active_template_id=}")
                for sub in formula.children:
                    print (f"\t\t\t{sub.id=}, {sub.old_id=}, {sub.model_id=}, {sub.old_model_id=}, {sub.parent_id=}, {sub.old_parent_id=}, {sub.active_template_id=}")

    print ('='*80)
    print (f'{total_count=}')


def apply_template(db, data: TemplateJsonSchema, company_id, payload: ApplyTemplateSchema):

    template_id = payload.template_id
    branch_id = payload.target_branch_id

    # Run this insert through and get id back.
    q = insert(ActiveTemplate).returning(ActiveTemplate.id).values(company_id=company_id, template_id=template_id,
                                     start_date=payload.start_date, branch_id=branch_id)
    active_template_id = db.execute(q).scalar()

    # These are unique when filtered by active template id
    # We store the old id of each model
    db.execute(insert(ModelCalculation.__table__), [dict(
        payload=model.payload,
        old_id=model.id,
        active_template_id=active_template_id) for model in data.models])

    # We store the old fk from each dashboard to model
    db.execute(insert(Dashboard.__table__), [dict(
        active_template_id=active_template_id,
        old_id=dashboard.id, old_model_id=dashboard.model_id,
        payload=dashboard.payload) for dashboard in data.dashboards])

    # We store the old fk from each dashboard to model
    db.execute(insert(Formula.__table__), [dict(
        active_template_id=active_template_id,
        old_id=f.id,
        old_parent_id=f.parent_id,
        old_model_id=f.model_id,
        payload=f.payload) for f in data.formulas])

    # Now we leverage the old_model_id to old_id connection to re-sync
    db.execute(update(Dashboard.__table__).values(model_id=ModelCalculation.id).where(
        Dashboard.old_model_id == ModelCalculation.old_id,
        Dashboard.active_template_id==active_template_id,
        ModelCalculation.active_template_id == active_template_id))

    # Same but for model id
    db.execute(update(Formula.__table__).values(model_id=ModelCalculation.id).where(
        Formula.old_model_id == ModelCalculation.old_id,
        Formula.active_template_id==active_template_id,
        ModelCalculation.active_template_id == active_template_id))

    # Same but for parent id
    f2 = aliased(Formula, name='f2')
    db.execute(update(Formula.__table__).values(parent_id=f2.id).where(
        Formula.old_parent_id == f2.old_id,
        Formula.active_template_id==active_template_id,
        f2.active_template_id == active_template_id))

    q = select(
        ActiveTemplate
    ).where(
        ActiveTemplate.id == active_template_id
    ).options(
        selectinload(
            ActiveTemplate.models
        ).options(selectinload(
            ModelCalculation.dashboards), selectinload(ModelCalculation.formulas).joinedload(Formula.children)))
    return db.scalar(q)


def main(env):
    engine = get_engine(env)
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        init_db(conn)
        with Session(conn) as db:
            mock_apply_template(db)
            db.commit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(os.environ)

